# Convert pandas datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

I have a column in a pandas data frame that contains datetime objects after applying the pd.to_datetime() method.
So far so good. Now the column contains the dates in a the form '2016-02-08 09:59:00.510'.
However, I would like to somehow 'drop' the date information, producing input in the form HH:MM:SS, like this:

2016-02-08 09:59:00.510 --> 09:59:00

I was wondering, if that is possible and if so, I would really appreciate some hints to the right way to do that.

Below there is a small working example. I was able to convert the datetime objects to integers (ns?) but I couldn't find out how to convert the objects in column 'Date' to the format I want.

As mentioned: Any help is highly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import time

s1 = {'Timestamp' : ['20160208_095900.51','20160208_095901.51','20160208_095902.51','20160208_095903.51',
                     '20160208_095904.51','20160208_095905.51','20160208_095906.51','20160208_095907.51',
                     '20160208_095908.51','20160208_095909.51']}

    df = pd.DataFrame(s1)

    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format =  '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.%f')
    df['ns'] = (df['Date'].astype(np.int64) / int(1e6))
    print df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a new string representation then use `dt.strftime`:

```
In [7]:
df['Time'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df

Out[7]:
            Timestamp                    Date      Time
0  20160208_095900.51 2016-02-08 09:59:00.510  09:59:00
1  20160208_095901.51 2016-02-08 09:59:01.510  09:59:01
2  20160208_095902.51 2016-02-08 09:59:02.510  09:59:02
3  20160208_095903.51 2016-02-08 09:59:03.510  09:59:03
4  20160208_095904.51 2016-02-08 09:59:04.510  09:59:04
5  20160208_095905.51 2016-02-08 09:59:05.510  09:59:05
6  20160208_095906.51 2016-02-08 09:59:06.510  09:59:06
7  20160208_095907.51 2016-02-08 09:59:07.510  09:59:07
8  20160208_095908.51 2016-02-08 09:59:08.510  09:59:08
9  20160208_095909.51 2016-02-08 09:59:09.510  09:59:09
```

If you want the `datetime.time` component then use `dt.time`:

```
In [8]:
df['Time'] = df['Date'].dt.time
df

Out[8]:
            Timestamp                    Date             Time
0  20160208_095900.51 2016-02-08 09:59:00.510  09:59:00.510000
1  20160208_095901.51 2016-02-08 09:59:01.510  09:59:01.510000
2  20160208_095902.51 2016-02-08 09:59:02.510  09:59:02.510000
3  20160208_095903.51 2016-02-08 09:59:03.510  09:59:03.510000
4  20160208_095904.51 2016-02-08 09:59:04.510  09:59:04.510000
5  20160208_095905.51 2016-02-08 09:59:05.510  09:59:05.510000
6  20160208_095906.51 2016-02-08 09:59:06.510  09:59:06.510000
7  20160208_095907.51 2016-02-08 09:59:07.510  09:59:07.510000
8  20160208_095908.51 2016-02-08 09:59:08.510  09:59:08.510000
9  20160208_095909.51 2016-02-08 09:59:09.510  09:59:09.510000
```

Comment: When would you prefer `df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')` over `df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))`?

Comment: @JohnGalt one should avoid `apply` if there exists a vectorised method, also I think `dt.strftime` was added on `0.17.0` so you'd have to use `apply` for older versions

Comment: @EdChum -- agreed. vector methods perform faster on larger data. You could perhaps stick to apply when dealing with smaller data. Check the benchmarks here http://pastebin.com/fyeqy05y